# How to query one column and display result into two columns

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have two worksheets that I want to combine into 1 sheets called "Mastersheet tab"

This is my query in my 'Mastersheet tab'
=Query({'Cut request '!A2:S;'Out sent '!A2:S},"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3,Col10,Col13,Col17,Col19 Where Col4 is not null",0)

Both of my sheets 'Cut request' and 'Out sent' have actually 16 columns

I want that the 16th column of 'Out sent' tab be separated in column into my 'Mastersheet tab'

What I did now is adding a sheet to 'Out sent' tab just to make a query and separate the column but not the good idea really. I want to keep the equal 16 column instead of 19 in 'Cut request' and 'Out sent' tab.

So can anyone help, please?

Thank you in advance. 12Rev79

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting the column you want `'Out sent '!P2:P` in the array formula in the query source:

`{'Cut request '!A2:P,'Cut request '!Z2:Z;'Out sent '!A2:P,'Out sent '!P2:P}`

where `'Cut request '!Z2:Z` is any empty column from the `'Cut request'` sheet. It must be added to make sure that the sizes of the arrays to be merged are the same

and then your final query will look like this:

`=Query({'Cut request '!A2:P,'Cut request '!Z2:Z;'Out sent '!A2:P,'Out sent '!P2:P},"Select Col1,Col2,Col4,Col3,Col10,Col13,Col17 Where Col4 is not null",0)`

Comment: thank you so much for your kind help. @ Sergey